# traffic forwarding with scapy between two interfaces

Tags: scapy

Hello I want to forward traffic between two interfaces to manipulate the packages between them (mitm). Here is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *

interfaces = {
"plc": "ens19",
"io": "ens20"
}
def pkt_PLC(pkt):
    return True

def pkt_IO(pkt):
    return True

def bridge():
    bridge_and_sniff(interfaces["plc"], interfaces["io"], 
        xfrm12=pkt_PLC, xfrm21=pkt_io,
         count=0, store=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf.sniff_promisc=True
    bridge()
```

The script is working and forwarding the traffic. My Problem is know that through the two interfaces is running are large amount of packages and the connection is not allowed to stop. My Problem is know that when i am looking at wireshark i can see that the connection is at points cut because not all the traffic is forwarded ,and so the application from which i am getting the traffic is stopped, after the short stop the traffic is again re transmitted. The process with stoping and res transmitting is repeated all the time. Ifthink

The setup is an industrial control station which is communicating with provinet. The component which i am siting between is the plc and and the rest of the system. When the system is starting it builds a connection with the rest of its components over profinet and continuously sends after that packages with profinet. Now if the communication is cut one needs to reset the error messages that the system can run again. Per second are about 3000 packages transmited.

Comment: Did you search their [GitHub](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+bridge_and_sniff) for any known issues or related issues others have had?

Comment: Like, what kind of traffic? I think there is not enough debug data provided to make any good point about whats happening :-/

Comment: It's an educational station that's not in the internet and only running when i turn it on, so no Problem on any law front. And my Problem is that the traffic is not all the time forwarded. I think that i have to somehow change the performance.